# Passing an array from Codeigniter to Smarty

Tags: codeigniter, smarty

I'm using Codeigniter with Smarty as my template engine. I have a main template
(master.tpl) that I am inheriting in my page templates. In one of my pages I'm trying to access data that was pulled from the database, but I have not been successful yet.

My model looks like this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
Class company extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {       
        // Call the constructor
        parent::__construct();

        // Load database access 
        $this->load->database(); 
    }

    public function get_companies()
    {
        // Query the companies table
        $query = $this->db->get('companies');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Companies extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        // Load the companies model
        $this->load->model('company');
        $companies = $this->company->get_companies();
        $data['complist'] = $companies;
        //load the department_view
        $this->load->view('companies',$data);
    }
}
```

and this is the main part of my page view:

```
...
<tbody>
    {foreach from=$companies item=company}
        <li>{$data.name}</li>
    {/foreach}
</tbody>
...
```

The code block in my  master.tpl that is inherited in the page view looks like this:
    ...
    
        {block name=content}{/block}
    
    ...

I'm simply trying to display a list of companies retrieved from my database but I can't figure out how to access the array that holds the data. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: 
Here are a the error messages I get:

```
Message: Undefined index: companies
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
```

Comment: Not sure if will work, but you are looking for variable `$complist`.

Comment: Thanks Tpojka, that was certainly part of the problem. : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tpojka mentioned, I was trying to access the wrong variable so I had to change that, but the syntax in the foreach loop was $companies->name. This is what the loop in the template now looks like:

```
{foreach from=$companies item=company}
    <tr>
        <td>{$company->name}</td>
        <td>{$company->address}</td>
        <td>{$company->city}</td>
        <td><a href="tel:{$company->phone}">{$company->phone}</a><td>
        <td><a href="mailto:{$company->email_address}">{$company->email_address}</a></td>
        <td class="center">
            <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-search-plus "></i>  
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-edit "></i>  
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o "></i> 
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
{foreachelse}
    No records found.
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making companies like so `$data['companies'] = $this->company->get_companies();`

**And autoload your database library in config/autoload.php much better.**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Companies extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {
    $this->load->model('company');
    $data['companies'] = $this->company->get_companies();

    $this->load->view('companies',$data);
}
}
```

Model

Make Model Class change **company** to **Company**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Company extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {       
       parent::__construct(); 
    }

    public function get_companies() {

    $query = $this->db->get('companies');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $query->result();

    // or 

    // return $query->result_array();

    } else {

    return false;

    }

}
```

On view I know you use smarty but php way Example normal php on view with out smarty just example.

```
<?php foreach ($companies as $company) {?>

<?php echo $company['name'];?>

<?php }?>
```

Smarty

```
<tbody>
    {foreach from = $companies item = $company}
        <tr>
        <td>{$company.name}</td>
        </tr>
    {/foreach}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you wolfgang, I did incorporate some of your suggestions. The syntax I had to use in the foreach loop was {$company->name}. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would be nice if you could accepted answer or vote up